# "What type of transistor?" Where does this question go?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I want to ask the question below but I don't know if it belongs to the *Raspberry Pi Exchange* or to the *Electrical Engineering Exchange*.

> **Will this work and what transistor do I use?**
>
> I have [this](http://www.ikea.com/gb/en/catalog/products/00321398/) Ikea lamp. It runs off 5V usb power however it draws 0.6A which according to [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/9298/what-is-the-maximum-current-the-gpio-pins-can-output) is more than the GPIO pins can supply. So I need to use a transistor but I don't know how to find one that will work.[image: Diagram of what I want to do]

**Edit**

I have posted this question [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/255122/will-this-work-and-what-transistor-do-i-use) with some modifications.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This question seems better aligned with our [**Electrical Engineering**](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) site. The use of Raspberry Pi is largely *coincidental* to the subject of this question, and our Electrical Engineering site has its roots as an Electronics Stack Exchange.

Comment: Yes, but speaking as an EE.SE moderator, a question as ill-formed as this is not going to be received well there. The whole premise that a RasPi + a transistor is the right approach to limiting the current to a lamp is totally flawed. Be sure to take our tour before posting there!